# How to recover Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I stuck at **Startup Recovery** every time I start windows 7, I think this is due to directly shutdown during the safe mode was being starting.
So, I'm having only access to command prompt with administrator mode, can anyone please suggest me what to do, I think some system file may be damaged!

Answer (score 2):

Often times in these cases (if there is some corruption) you are able to repair them. These steps work in most cases when there are file corrupted.

1. With the command prompt you already have available try this `chkdsk /x /f /r c:`. Press 'y' and enter to say you want to restart your computer. (Note: If it rejects saying there is nothing at "C" look at step number 8 and get Windows' drive letter). If it works when done scanning your disk for errors and fixing, celebrate; if not, proceed.

I'm not sure if it will accept these next two commands depending if we are "online" but there is a good chance

2. In command prompt run `sfc /scannow`. Wait for it, once done restart. If this works, celebrate; if not, proceed.
3. In command prompt run `DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`. If it says that it can't work on an online drive run this instead: `DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth`. (Note: If it rejects saying there is nothing at "C" look at step number 8 and get Windows' drive letter). If this works, celebrate; if not, proceed diligently
4. Download the Windows 7 ISO from Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7) with another computer.
5. Either burn it to a disk (find directions online) or as I recommend put it on a flash drive with more than 3.2 GB (at the moment, minimum depends on ISO file's size). Use the tool called [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to put it on the flash drive. Now you may have to try and repeat till this boots correctly in the next step. If you are using Windows 7 then it is likely (and if it came with windows 7 new it is very likely) BIOS and MBR. If that doesn't boot try UEFI and MBR. You select these in the rufus drop down menu.
6. Boot up to it. Sometimes you can press Esc to give you a menu. Else you may have to try out some F1-F12 keys. Or choose what it says if it shows the keys to press. You can also go to BIOS and change the boot order to the device you are using.
7. Once it loads to the Windows Install screen click "Repair your computer" then choose "Startup Repair. Restart your computer. Check if it works and if so celebrate. If not proceed.
8. Get back to  "Repair your computer" and choose "Command Prompt." Run `diskpart`, then in diskpart run `list vol`. Remember the drive letter of the Windows 7 OS (you can tell by looking at the size or if it says "Windows" (note: it doesn't usually say it)). Also remember the drive letter of the flash drive (or whatever you are using). If it doesn't have a drive letter `select vol #` (replace # with whatever number it is). Run this `assign letter=W` (Replace W with whatever letter is available). Exit diskpart by typing `exit`.
9. You already done this one, but try it again for good measure. If it did not work or run last time, it should work this time. Type this (replace the driver letter where the drive windows is on) `chkdsk w: /x /f /r`  Restart your computer if it works, celebrate; if not, proceed diligently.
10. Type this (replace the driver letters respectively where the image is what drive windows is on and the source is whatever you put the ISO on) and wait for it: `DISM /image:W:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:N:\sources\install.wim` Once done type `exit`. Restart your computer if it works, celebrate; if not, proceed diligently.
11. Get back to "Repair your computer" and choose "System Restore." If there is a rollback date select it. When it is done, restart and try. If not, proceed.
12. Get back to "Repair your computer" and select "System Image Recovery." Note: If there is a rollback date select it. You will loose all files that were created AFTER the Image's Date. When done, restart your computer; if it works, celebrate; if not, proceed diligently.
13. At this point if there are files you want to recover and save, consult the web for help (or post another question, after extensive searching for guides on how to) to help you do so.
14. Last resort, reinstall the operating system by choosing "Install."
    Hope it works!